# How to install a rearview mirror in a car?

Tags: mirrors

My rearview mirror fell from the front windshield. How shall I install it back?

All youtube video tutorial tells to install the mirror to the glass but not the plastic part. But the rear was used to install to a plastic tab marked by the yellow circle. When I put the glue on the plastic tab, the mirror fell off easily. [image]

Comment: Thanks @Solar Mike. I am able to use your answer and find some brands that could work for plastic: 1) 3M Rearview Mirror Adhesive; 2) Permatex General Purpose Epoxy; 3) J-B Weld ClearWeld (most plastic). The list is from this link: https://www.thedrive.com/reviews/28508/best-rear-view-mirror-glues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either remove the plastic and get special glue for glass and it is special requiring cleaning with particular products which are usually supplied as part of the kit or get the glue suitable for the plastic.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a brand name for the glue suitable for the plastic?

Comment: @zhanxw asking for brand names is about to make this into a shopping question which will be closed as off-topic. The ones I used may not be available in your area. You have to read the instructions on the packet.